# How to do hide and show element on specific page position on scroll always when getting to that place with jquery on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am tring to hide and show the logo when getting to some position of page with this code

```
 var scrol_pos = jQuery(".video_cats_row").offset().top;;
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() { 
     if($(window).scrollTop() >= scrol_pos){
          if(!jQuery('.teenvoice_smalllogo img').hasClass('slideInLeft')){
                jQuery('.teenvoice_smalllogo img').addClass('slideInLeft');
                jQuery('.teenvoice_smalllogo img').show();
            }
            if(jQuery('.teenvoice_smalllogo img').hasClass('slideOutLeft')){
                jQuery('.teenvoice_smalllogo img').removeClass('slideOutLeft');
            }
     }else{
         jQuery('.teenvoice_smalllogo img').hide();
     }
      if($(window).scrollTop() === '0'){
           jQuery('.teenvoice_smalllogo img').hide();
      }
  });
```

But it is working only once and when I go up and then down it didnt check and do this same action.How to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried moving `var scrol_pos = jQuery(".video_cats_row").offset().top;` within the scroll function?

Comment: no didnt work checked

Comment: any ideas @JamieBarker?

Comment: You're wanting `.teenvoice_smalllogo img` to be visible at what point? Currently you're checking for the top of the window to be lower than the top of `.video_cats_row`

Comment: Yes it should be visible when I reached to the div video_cats_row and to the bottom from it and hidden at the very top and till I reach video_cats_row

Comment: Could you try to include a html in a jsfiddle? It will be easier to understand with your complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you're wanting it to work like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/d9j90vse/

```js
var checkScroll = function() {
  if ($('.video_cats_row')[0]) {
    var el = $('.video_cats_row');
    var top_of_object = el.offset().top;
    var bottom_of_object = el.offset().top + el.outerHeight();
    var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    if (top_of_window <= bottom_of_object && bottom_of_window >= top_of_object) {
      $('.teenvoice_smalllogo').show();
    } else {
      $('.teenvoice_smalllogo').hide();
    }
  }
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  checkScroll()
});
```

```css
.teenvoice_smalllogo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}
.video_cats_row {
  margin: 1300px 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  line-height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="teenvoice_smalllogo">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="video_cats_row">[INSERT CATS VIDEO HERE]</div>
```